Looking for manwha about guy with no powers accidentally invited to group chat with top players
I am looking for help in finding a manwha about this topic.
From what I can remember it is about an old guy who is in the dumps because he can't unlock his powers or he doesn't have them, and one day he is accidentally invited to a group chat containing gods or top players.  He doesn't think they are at first until one of them shows up in his room and talk with him a bit before leaving.  One day, he gets drunk and types in the chat about how he is sad for being weak and wants to get stronger, and the next day he is taken by an assassin like player to train him.
This is what I can remember and was in the first 4 to 5 chapters.  Hope you can help me find it.

There are a few Manhwa with that premise. One of the first ones was Cultivation Chat Group by Legend of the Paladin. It started as a webnovel, and then was turned into a manhua.


Song Shuhang, a modern-day student, is accidentally added to an online chat group full of people who discuss supernatural things such as cultivation, monsters, tribulation, and so on; slowly, he learns that this world is real and joins it himself.

Not matching, it's a college student.

https://www.novelupdatesforum.com/threads/mc-gets-added-to-a-supernatural-cultivation-chat-group.110543/ has other possibilities.
